# Dynamic SQL queries as parameter

Tags: sql, pentaho, where-clause, pentaho-report-designer

I need a Report where a user has to choose 2 parameters. The first parameter contains the years (2017, 2016...), and the second one contains the ID process. Depending on the process that the user chooses, the SQL statement will be one or another. The parameter year is part of the WHERE clause of the SQL contained in the second parameter.

So I have this report with 2 parameters (`param_year`, `Indicador`). Query parameter is done using a table datasource, where the IDs column contains the SQL sentences and the Values column contains the text the user must select.

[image: Setting the parameter]

So what I'm doing next is to `set ${Indicador}` as the SQL statement in the JDBC connection that I have done to the Database. This is reporting me an SQL error

> "Failed at query: ${Indicador}.

[image: Setting the parameter as the SQL statement]

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to **create multiple datasources** in your Master/sub report, then **select appropriate datasource using PRD expression** on `Master/sub Report -> Attributes -> query -> name` attribute.

**More detailed explanation:**

1. Create a query (I mean a query as a PRD object, which uses the PRD datasource) for every SQL string you need and move the SQL strings from the parameter table into Report Designer queries definitions.
2. Replace the SQL strings in your parameter table with names of corresponding queries, e.g:
   [image: parameter table]
3. Use the value of your parameter (which should be equal to the PRD query name) as value for `Master/sub Report -> Attributes -> query -> name` attribute: 
   [image: query name expression]

Answer (score 0):

You need Pentaho Data Integration to do this kind of dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

If the table structure (output columns) for both queries is the same, you could put them together into one big SQL statement with UNION ALL and put in each query "WHERE ${Indicador} = ValueToRunThisQuery".

The optimizer *should* be smart enough to know the not-selected subquery is going to return zero rows and not even run it. You can supply a few null columns if one query has fewer columns, but the data types have to be the same for filled columns.

If the output table structure is different between the two queries they should be in different data sources, or even reports.

```
SELECT ID, BLA, BLA, BLA, ONLY_IN_A
FROM TABLE A
WHERE ${Indicador} = "S010"
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, BLA, BLA, BLA, NULL
FROM TABLE B
WHERE ${Indicador} = "S020"
```